# calling a button or a textfield from another class | android

Tags: android

i have tried to use the edittext in the list select listener but it can't see it from the main activity 
taking me to error at this

```
edt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

so please if you have anything around help me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static int HELLO_ID = 1;
boolean flag = false;
CountDownTimer timer;
//the strings of the notifications
String titlePills = "Time to take Panadol",DescriptionPills  = "Panadol";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
         R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerActivity());


 Chronometer test = new Chronometer(this);
 Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


 //hide the button and the edit text
 btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 edt.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}
//*********************************************************************************
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {


    public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {

        String select = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();



        if(select.equals("Type the timee"))
        {
        //edt error can't be resolved 
            edt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: If you want to Handle on the selected Value in SpinnerActivity try to call it with startActivityForResult and handle the result to set the Visibility of your edt. It is only one Activity shown so why you want to change its Viewstate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
EditText edt;
```

as globle variable

```
edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```